# Redux-thunk ThunkDispatch type fails when passing an interface to `dispatch<ShowSnackbar>({})`

Tags: typescript, redux, typescript-typings, redux-thunk

When applying an interface to my redux thunk action's `dispatch()` function, error checking seems wrong. 
For example if I comment out a property, Typescript complains about the one that's actually enabled, saying that its missing:

```
...

type ThunkResult<R> = ThunkAction<R, RootState, undefined, Action>;

export interface ShowSnackbar {
  type: string,
  isOpened: boolean
}

export const showSnackbar = (): ThunkResult<void> => (dispatch, getState) => {

    dispatch<ShowSnackbar>({
        // type: 'baz',
        isOpened: true // <-- 'isOpened' does not exist in type 'ThunkAction<ShowSnackbar ...
    });

}
```

After inspecting the redux-thunk ThunkDispatch type, I noticed that the first function declaration of the overloaded functions gets ignored and the second that expects a function was called when my action has a commented out property (intentionally introduced error):

```
export interface ThunkDispatch<S, E, A extends Action> {
  <T extends A>(action: T): T;
  <R>(asyncAction: ThunkAction<R, S, E, A>): R;
}
```

If say, I delete `<R>(asyncAction: ThunkAction<R, S, E, A>): R;`, type checking gets back to normal, and TS will warn me correctly:

> 'type' is missing in type '{ isOpened: true; }' but required in type
>   'ShowSnackbar'.

I have put together a [demo on TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%2F%2F%20--%20Store%20--%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20RootState%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20state%3A%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F--%20Types%20--%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20Action%3CT%20%3D%20any%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20T%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20ThunkDispatch%3CS%2C%20E%2C%20A%20extends%20Action%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3CT%20extends%20A%3E(action%3A%20T)%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%20%20%3CR%3E(asyncAction%3A%20ThunkAction%3CR%2C%20S%2C%20E%2C%20A%3E)%3A%20R%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20type%20ThunkAction%3CR%2C%20S%2C%20E%2C%20A%20extends%20Action%3E%20%3D%20(%0D%0A%20%20dispatch%3A%20ThunkDispatch%3CS%2C%20E%2C%20A%3E%2C%0D%0A%20%20getState%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20S%2C%0D%0A%20%20extraArgument%3A%20E%0D%0A)%20%3D%3E%20R%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F--%20Action%20Creators%20--%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ThunkResult%3CR%3E%20%3D%20ThunkAction%3CR%2C%20RootState%2C%20undefined%2C%20Action%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20ShowSnackbar%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20isOpened%3A%20boolean%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20const%20showSnackbar%20%3D%20()%3A%20ThunkResult%3Cvoid%3E%20%3D%3E%20(dispatch%2C%20getState)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20dispatch%3CShowSnackbar%3E(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20type%3A%20'baz'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20isOpened%3A%20true%20%2F%2F%20%3C--%20'isOpened'%20does%20not%20exist%20in%20type%20'ThunkAction%3CShowSnackbar%20...%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D) that demonstrates the issue.

Or I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript gets confused here since it has two possibilities to try out. If you switch the order of `ThunkDispatch`, you already get to the error message you want to see in the first place:

```
export interface ThunkDispatch<S, E, A extends Action> {
  <R>(asyncAction: ThunkAction<R, S, E, A>): R;
  <T extends A>(action: T): T;
}
```

> Argument of type '{ isOpened: true; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ShowSnackbar'.
>     Property 'type' is missing in type '{ isOpened: true; }' but required in type 'ShowSnackbar'.

As an aside: I'd suggest adding `extends Action<string>` (or `Action<'baz'>`) to your `ShowSnackbar` interface and remove the `type: string` from its definition. This way you will keep being an `Action`, even if you later decide to change something on the Action. Or at least, you'll receive error messages, when you decide to change the name `type` to something else for example.

Comment: Yes this makes sense. Thanks for the suggestion related to my interface!